# How to declare imageview without set/inflate the layout?

Tags: android, layout, imageview

is there any code to declare the imageview and set imageresource without inflate the layout ?

i am create listview adapter in other layout, so i didnt inflate the layout. 
but ineed to set image to the imageview.

this is my code but its not working

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list_request,    container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    rlRequestWorkflow = (RelativeLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.rlListRequestWorkflow);
    listPhoto = (ImageView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listPhoto);
    rlRequestWorkflow.addView(listPhoto);
 }
```

this is my current layout (main class)

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/flRequest"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
tools:context="com.ITK.SMP.Native.Workflow.ListRequest">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lvRequest"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
      />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is listadapter class

```
public class ListRequestAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListRequestItem> {
ImageView listPhoto;

public ListRequestAdapter(Context context, List<ListRequestItem> items)
{
    super(context, R.layout.style_fragment_list_request, items);

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if(convertView == null) {
        // inflate the GridView item layout
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.style_fragment_list_request, parent, false);

        // initialize the view holder
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.tvTanggal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTanggalRequest);
        viewHolder.tvTipe = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTipeRequest);
        viewHolder.tvStatus = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);
        viewHolder.permitid = "";
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        // recycle the already inflated view
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // update the item view
    ListRequestItem item = getItem(position);
    viewHolder.tvTanggal.setText(item.tanggal);
    viewHolder.tvTipe.setText(item.tipe);
    viewHolder.tvStatus.setText(item.status);
    viewHolder.permitid = item.permitid;
    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tvTanggal;
    TextView tvTipe;
    TextView tvStatus;
    String permitid;
}
```

}

this is the imageview in the listadapterlayout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:tag="reqtag"
android:id="@+id/rlListRequestWorkflow"
>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!--ImageView here-->
        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/listPhoto"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="63dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!--All textViews here-->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Type"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:id="@+id/tvTipeRequest"
            android:width="130dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Date"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:id="@+id/tvTanggalRequest"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:width="130dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:text="Status"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:id="@+id/tvStatus"
            android:layout_column="38" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: do not add image view in xml, pass it using a constructor.

Comment: how to pass using a constructor?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to inflate your imageview, then pass your imageview in the constructor of class, and set the image from there.

Suppose, MainActivity is the class where your image view is present

MainActivity.class

```
ImageView imageview;
imageview=(ImageView)findViewById(R.Id.imageview);

new ListAdapter(imageview);
```

ListAdapter.class

```
ImageView imageview;
//constructor
public ListAdapter(ImageView imageview){
  this.imageview=imageview;
}

//now you can use imageview to set image
```

Comment: how to do pass using constructor?

Comment: just pass your imageview object in constructor

Comment: sorry i still dont get it, can you write the sample code ?

Comment: hey ranjan, thanks for the answer. im affraid i cant do that since my listadapter class are array adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Edit this:-
 rlRequestWorkflow = (RelativeLayout)**view**.findViewById(R.id.rlListRequestWorkflow);
    listPhoto = (ImageView)**view**.findViewById(R.id.listPhoto);